# How to create an Alexa app to fetch users current location and tell him about my nearest office?

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

I am trying to create an app for my own business. I have 5 stores and I want an alexa app to tell the users that this particular store is closest to you go to this store.
Any help, any direction would be helpful.

Comment: Rohan, you would utilize the DeviceAddressServiceClient as outlined in the ask-sdk documentation. https://ask-sdk-for-nodejs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Calling-Alexa-Service-APIs.html and then base the closest store call against this information.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Device Address API` to get address data for your skill.

Every request from Alexa will have an  `apiAccessToken` included in its payload. You can use this  `apiAccessToken` to fire appropriate request to the `apiEndpoint` mentioned in the Alexa request payload.

Simple having the `apiAccessToken` doesn't mean that you have access to resources (like address). You have to obtain the customer's permission to use address data associated with the customer's Alexa device. For this, users will have to either explicitly grant access to your skill under `Settings` menu of your Alexa skill or you will have to send a `permission card` to the user for consent.

In ask-node-sdk v2 you can send a permission card like this:

```
return handlerInput.responseBuilder
      .speak(speechOutput)
      .withAskForPermissionsConsentCard(['read::alexa:device:all:address'])
      .getResponse();
```

where `read::alexa:device:all:address` is the permission value for Device Full Address.

Once the permission is granted, fire a `GET` request with `deviceId` and `apiAccessToken` to the specified `apiEndpoint`

Endpoint for Full Address is: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address`

Country/region & postal code: `/v1/devices/*deviceId*/settings/address/countryAndPostalCode`

In ask-node-sdk v2 you can get address information like this:

```
const deviceAddressServiceClient = serviceClientFactory.getDeviceAddressServiceClient();
const address = await deviceAddressServiceClient.getFullAddress(deviceId);
```

**Note:** Requests from Alexa may also include a `consentToken` within `session.user.permissions` and `context.System.user.permissions`. This property is deprecated and the `context.System.apiAccessToken` property should be used instead.

More on Device Address API [here](https://developer.amazon.com/docs/custom-skills/device-address-api.html)